# Very slow loading of records with datatables plugin, how can I do faster?

Tags: datatable, record

I have been trying to load the content of a single query for days, I have tried both from the server side and server client directly and both do not work take the same.

Currently the charging time can be approximately one minute.

I have incorporated the "scroller" plugin but it takes the same, someone can help me, I leave the code here, use php and codeigniter 3.

JS

```
var table = $('#datatabletransaction').DataTable({
"deferRender":    true,
"scrollY":        500,
"scroller":       true,
"responsive": true,
"processing": true,
"fixedHeader": true,
"serverSide":true,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "Todos"]],
    "ajax": {
        "url": mostrarcontenido,
        "type": "POST"
},       
language": {
      "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
},
"fixedColumns": true,
"iDisplayLength": 5,
"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function mostrartablatransaccionestelefonos(){
  $this->load->model('tablas_model');
  $data = array();
  $list = $this->tablas_model->mostrar_registros_ventacompra($estado);
  foreach ($list as $person) {
      $row = array();
      $row[] = $person->num_factura;
      $row[] = $person->num_albaran;
      $row[] = $person->transacion;
      $row[] = $person->imei;
      $row[] = $person->nombre;
      $row[] = $person->fecha_registro;
      $row[] = $person->modelo;
      $row[] = $person->marca;
      $row[] = $person->color;
      $row[] = $person->memoria;
      $row[] = $person->precio_iva;
      $row[] = $person->precio_sin_iva;

      $output = array(
              "data" => $data,
      );
      echo json_encode($output);
```

}

The query is very wide, but I will put the response time that the query returns (made with HeidSql).

I have executed the query in HeidiSql and this is the result
/ * Affected rows: 0 Rows found: 1.816 Warnings: 0 Duration for 1 consultation: 0.047 sec. * /

The query does not take half a second.
But how can I make it load data faster?

I have tried these options but without result:

https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html

Answer (score 0):

i think your Controller is buggy.

1. Width this code you will add 12 Rows to your $row array, is this what you want?
2. The output array contains an empty $data element, you are not filling it anywhere.

To start debugging your slow performance you should try to call the controller and look where you loos so much time

- if you call the controller with something like Postman, in what time is it responding?
- if the problem is the controller put some [microtime(true)](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php) calls to your code and monitore where the slow part.

good luck

Comment: Hi, the controller is correctly, the controller calls the model to execute a query which returns records in the form of an object.

You can see info in the doc Codeigniter:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: In addition the json is returning correctly:
{"data":[["1","","Compra","202020000000000","IKey","2019-10-07 19:17:58","Samsung Galaxy S7 libre","Samsung","Dorado","32GB","150.00","123.97"